# Как перевести время в timestamp?

Tags: c#

Данный код генерит 10-знаковый timestamp. А мне нужно 16

```
int unixTime = (int)(DateTime.UtcNow - new DateTime(1970, 1, 1)).TotalSeconds;
```

Нашёл в инете код для операции преобразования 16-значного в timestamp

```
var timestamp = 1582799824092200;
var epoch = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc);
var myDate = epoch.AddMilliseconds(timestamp / 1000);
```

Comment: Странная задача. Вы хотите не timestamp. `The unix time stamp is a way to track time as a running total of *seconds*. `

Comment: @ЕвгенийБорисов а как оно называется правильно

Comment: А что это у вас за такой редкий или самопальный стандарт? Мы не знаем. Я например, могу лишь попробовать угадать: может вам просто дополнить ведущими нулями?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Возможно вам надо что то вроде этого (копипаста из какого то моего древнего проекта)

```
public static double ToUnixTicks(this DateTime dt)
{
    DateTime d1 = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1);
    DateTime d2 = dt.ToUniversalTime();
    TimeSpan ts = new TimeSpan(d2.Ticks - d1.Ticks);
    return ts.TotalMilliseconds;
}

public static DateTime FromUnixTicks(this double ms)
{
    DateTime d1 = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1);
    return d1.AddMilliseconds(ms).ToLocalTime();
}
```